# how to import rethinkdbdash in es2015

Tags: node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rethinkdb

I am new to programming in node.js. I have setup `gulp-babel` which takes my js files in /src and moves the transpiled source to /dist folder (which is working awesome).

I would like to use the `rethinkdbdash` instead of `rethinkdb`. In es5 we would do the following:

```
var r = require('rethinkdbdash')();
```

In es6 what would be the correct way of using the import?

```
import 'rethinkdbdash';
var r = rethinkdbdash();
```

Thanks for the help. I hope answer also helps others having the same issue as I am.

Comment: I did the following seems to work:import * as rethinkdbdash from 'rethinkdbdash'; var r = rethinkdbdash.default();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, it's default export, so import it like this:

```
import rethinkdbdash from 'rethinkdbdash';
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. but then you need to do rethinkdbdash.default() afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps to import using ES2015:

```
import rethinkdbdash from 'rethinkdbdash';

let r = rethinkdbdash();
```

If you need to pass parameters:

```
let r = rethinkdbdash({
      "db": "my database name",
      "servers": [
        {
          "host": "my server host name",
          "port": 28015
        }
      ]
});
```